# Dictionary<string, object> serialization in OData using ASP.Net MVC 5 and Web API 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using OData services over the new Web API for MVC 5 and I am experiencing some problems.

I have followed [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn201742.aspx) to start develop OData services and almost everything is right. The project builds, the routes work, and the URLs is working great.

One of my classes is called `Post` and have a property of type `Dictionary<string, object>` named `Parameters`, like below:

```
public partial class Post : IPost
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Author{ get; set; }  
    public string Content{ get; set; }  
    public DateTime PostedDate{ get; set; }  
    public List<Photo> Pictures { get; set; }  

    public Dictionary<string, object> Parameters { get; set; }  
}
```

The URL to list all the `Post` objects (`http://localhost/odata/Posts`) is working fine when I perform a get request in browser. All the objects are successfully serialized.

But importing the OData Metadata as a Service Reference in another application, when I get the list of `Post` entities, I get the error below:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.Data.OData.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The type
>   'WebApplication1.ServiceReference2.System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair_2OfString_Object'
>   has no settable properties.

How to resolve this problem for import Service References with success?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some days later I tried a lot of different tests.

- `Dictionary<string, object>` => throw the original error
- `Dictionary<string, string>` => same error
- `List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>` => same error
- `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` => same error

I realized the `KeyValuePair` class was the problem, but I didn't know why.

So, I created a class named `Parameter` like below:

```
public class Parameter
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

...I changed the list type to `List<Parameter>` and it worked!

After thinking more about the problem, I realized one important sentence in the error:

> 'WebApplication1.ServiceReference2.System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair_2OfString_Object'
>   **has no settable properties**

The dictionaries are nothing more than lists of KeyValue pairs, and the `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` struct have two properties, named "Key" and "Value", which have only get accessors. So, they are readonly.

We may conclude the OData Service Reference can't deserialize the readonly properties, by some reason I don't know yet.

My workaround worked, but I am wondering if the Service Reference may have someday a reflection way to set this properties.

Comment: I thought of trying ODATA for a couple of things, and now I get silly errors like this.What does this look like after you serialize it? I chose Dictionary because it it gives precisely the output I want when using Newtonsoft, or the WebAPI.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone who is reading this since > 2015: OData V4 supports open types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/use-open-types-in-odata-v4

Your dictionary should be of type:

`IDictionary<string, object>.`

Odata will then create an Open Type for you.

Comment: Is there a way to force oData to use named property instead of serializing properties in line? If I have IDictionary<string, object> Names, I want it to be serialized as { "Names" : {"engilish": "Name"}} instead of {"english": "Name"}

Answer (score 1):

web API OData doesn't support open types yet which I think is what you are looking for. `Dictionary<string, object>` doesn't model well in EDM.

Could you explain further what Post.Parameters is supposed to contain to see if there is a better way to model the Post type?

Comment: Did you ever get around to fixing this, i am experiencing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

OData now supports [Open Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/use-open-types-in-odata-v4) where you can use an `IDictionary` and OData creates the Open Type for you. But the example provided in the documentation is a straight forward case, where the class with Open Type has a dedicated controller.

In my case, I have a class that is a field of a bigger class being returned. The bigger class is an entity set with its own controller. The smaller class doesn't have a controller, and has a dictionary.

The set up look like this:

```
// Has its own controller and is an entity set
public class BiggerClass
{
   ... // fields that show up in response

   [Contained]
   public SmallerClass smallClass; // Data was partially available in the response
}

public class SmallerClass
{
   ... // fields that show up in response

   [Contained]
   public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, InnerClass>> Mapping; // Didn't show up in the response, but verified it was being set properly 
}

// Since the above mapping didn't show up, all of the objects of this class were missing
public class InnerClass
{
    ... // Only has primitives
}
```

The dictionary's content was not showing up. In addition to the `Contained` attributes, I had to add the following to my Odata builder:

```
builder.AddComplexType(typeof(SmallerClass));
builder.AddComplexType(typeof(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, InnerClass>>));
```

Note that adding `InnerClass` as a complex type didn't do anything, and the dictionary itself (the data structure not showing up) had to be added.

Comment: I did not have to add the "Contained" attributes to my model just to get it to serialize the properties.